# Remove particular block from specific store view

Tags: magento2

We can use following statement to remove the particular block, but this will remove it from all views.:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-sold" remove="true" />
```

Is their any way I can remove it from particular store view via layout only ?

Answer (score 0):

We can't remove blocks in the layout file based on store view. Please refer the below core file on how to remove blocks programmatically based on conditions. We need to create after plugin for your controller then remove block in afterExecute method based on your condition.

**Core example:**

**vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-shipping-admin-ui/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\View">
    <plugin name="shipment_tracking" type="Magento\InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi\Plugin\Shipping\Controller\Order\Shipment\View\ShipmentTrackingPlugin"/>
</type>
```

Create di.xml in your extension as like above and change your controller in the above plugin.

**vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-shipping-admin-ui/Plugin/Shipping/Controller/Order/Shipment/View/ShipmentTrackingPlugin.php**

```
public function afterExecute(View $subject, $result)
{
    if ($result instanceof Page) {
        
        if (write_your_condition_here_to_check_store_view) {
            $result->getLayout()->unsetElement('customer-sold');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Create plugin class in your extension as like above file and apply your condition.